# How do i make a custom adapter for a spinner

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, spinner, adapter

I want the adapter to change the textview on the spinner and change the background imageview on main activity. It would be easy if i could make an adapter that takes in an object(pet) with both the qualities  but I'm not sure how. The pet object has a string for the name of the pet and url for the downloadImage asyncTask My problem right now is that i get a null pointer exception. The constructor is confusing me as well. I just don't think the adapter is doing what it's supposed to. This is how I am doing it now:

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    //for layouts
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ArrayList<String> names;

    //
    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img1;
        TextView tv1;
        String url;
        Bitmap bitmap;
    }

    //generate data we use

    // private final MainActivity mainActivity;
    String tempUrl;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> pets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, pets);

        myInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();


        this.names = names;
        list = pets;
        tempUrl = "http://tetonsoftware.com/pets/";

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //set the text
        holder.tv1.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.url = tempUrl.concat(list.get(position));

        //start a thread to download image

        new DownloadImageTask(holder).execute(holder.url);
        //new ImageDownloader().execute(holder);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

```java
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String TAG = "DownloadImageTask";

    private static final int DEFAULTBUFFERSIZE = 50;
    private static final int NODATA = -1;
    private final CustomAdapter.ViewHolder myVH;

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Drawable placeholder;


    public DownloadImageTask(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder myVH) {
        this.myVH = myVH;
        this.url = myVH.url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        // site we want to connect to
        String url = params[0];

        // note streams are left willy-nilly here because it declutters the
        // example
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);

            // this does no network IO
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();

            // can further configure connection before getting data
            // cannot do this after connected
            // connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setReadTimeout(500);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(500);

            // this opens a connection, then sends GET & headers
            connection.connect();

            // lets see what we got make sure its one of
            // the 200 codes (there can be 100 of them
            // http_status / 100 != 2 does integer div any 200 code will = 2
            int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode / 100 != 2) {
                return null;
            }

            // get our streams, a more concise implementation is
            // BufferedInputStream bis = new
            // BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            // the following buffer will grow as needed
            ByteArrayOutputStream baf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(DEFAULTBUFFERSIZE);
            //ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(DEFAULTBUFFERSIZE);
            int current = 0;

            // wrap in finally so that stream bis is sure to close
            try {
                while ((current = bis.read()) != NODATA) {
                    baf.write((byte) current);
                }

                // convert to a bitmap
                byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
            } finally {
                // close resource no matter what exception occurs
                bis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Result for " + url);
        if (result != null) {

            if (url == this.myVH.url) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS for " + url);
                this.myVH.img1.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "FAIL url != this.myVH.url for " + url);
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "NULL for " + url);
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

> 04-02 19:55:37.252 10941-10941/com.example.arya.project3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.arya.project3, PID: 10941
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at com.example.arya.project3.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:106)
>                                                                                  at com.example.arya.project3.DownloadImageTask.onPostExecute(DownloadImageTask.java:17)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
>   04-02 19:55:37.253 10941-10941/com.example.arya.project3 I/AndroidRuntime: To Report FATAL to activityManagerService
>   04-02 19:55:37.364 10941-10941/com.example.arya.project3 I/AndroidRuntime: Finished reporting FATAL to activityManagerService
>   04-02 19:55:37.364 10941-10941/com.example.arya.project3 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10941 SIG: 9

Comment: If you have a Pet object use an ArrayAdapter<Pet> and use a List<Pet> in your constructor...and give the stacktrace of the npe.

Comment: what stack trace? @ElDuderino and could you be more specific

Comment: The text you get that says it is a null pointer exception, post it here. It says in which line of your code the error is...

Comment: @ElDuderino edited post with error message

Comment: The error is in this line : this.myVH.img1.setImageBitmap(result); so img1 seems to be null...probably because the view is recycled . do it like this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#async-task

Comment: Are you certain that your imageview's id matches the id in your viewholder?

Comment: @ElDuderino not really sure how to implement the WeakReference